C++ WebServer: Store (Thread-Safe Data Persistence) Part-3
I think I made a mistake trying to start from the simplest version and working forward. This time I will present the final version, get all the fixes from here and incorperat them into the code, then I can reverse engineer the steps to get there.
The Parts of the server are:

NisseServer: Part-5
EventHandler: Part-4
Store: Part-3
JobQueue: Part-2
Pynt: Part-1

This post deals only with Store.
This class is used to keep track of all state associated with open sockets.
I wanted to divide this class into two parts. Only the main thread can update the state. So all updates are done via processUpdateRequest(). Any thread can add call requestChange(T&& update) which queues a request to be handled by processUpdateRequest().
Store.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_STORE_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_STORE_H

#include "NisseConfig.h"
#include "NisseUtil.h"
#include "Pynt.h"
#include "EventHandlerLibEvent.h"
#include <ThorsSocket/Server.h>
#include <ThorsSocket/SocketStream.h>
#include <variant>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>

/*
 * The store can hold two types of object:
 *      ServerData:             Data needed by the listeners.
 *                              The ThorsSocket::Server object.
 *      StreamData:             Data needed by a connected socket that is communicating.
 *                              The ThorsSocket::SocketStream object.
 *
 * Addition both types hold the following information.
 *  2: Task                     A lambda that is executed.
 *  3: CoRoutine                A boost CoRoutine2 that allows code to yield if the socket blocks.
 *  4: LibEvent objects         These interact with the EventHandler to make sure that
 *                              callbacks activate the Co-Routine.
 *
 * When an object is first created we also active the LibEvent read Listener of that object.
 *
 * To make sure that this object is thread safe state change is only done by the master thread
 * via the method `processUpdateRequest()`. All other threads request state change
 * via the `requestChange()` method that enqueues a request to be done by the main thread.
 */

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse
{

/*
 * Data that can be stored.
 */
struct ServerData
{
    TAS::Server         server;
    CoRoutine           coRoutine;
    Event               readEvent;
    Pynt*               pynt;
};
struct StreamData
{
    TAS::SocketStream   stream;
    CoRoutine           coRoutine;
    Event               readEvent;
    Event               writeEvent;
    Pynt*               pynt;
};

using StoreData = std::variant<ServerData, StreamData>;


/*
 * Change request objects.
 * The following are objects that can be enqueued by requestChange()
 */
struct StateUpdateCreateServer
{
    int                 fd;
    TAS::Server         server;
    ServerCreator       coRoutineCreator;
    Event               readEvent;
    Pynt&               pynt;
};

struct StateUpdateCreateStream
{
    int                 fd;
    TAS::SocketStream   stream;
    StreamCreator       coRoutineCreator;
    Event               readEvent;
    Event               writeEvent;
    Pynt&               pynt;
};

struct StateUpdateRemove
{
    int     fd;
};

struct StateUpdateRestoreRead
{
    int fd;
};

struct StateUpdateRestoreWrite
{
    int fd;
};


using StateUpdate = std::variant<StateUpdateCreateServer, StateUpdateCreateStream, StateUpdateRemove, StateUpdateRestoreRead, StateUpdateRestoreWrite>;

/*
 * The store data
 */
class Store
{
    static CoRoutine    invalid;

    std::map<int, StoreData>    data;
    std::vector<StateUpdate>    updates;
    std::mutex                  updateMutex;

    public:
        StoreData&      getStoreData(int fd);
        void            processUpdateRequest();

        template<typename T>
        void requestChange(T&& update);
    private:
        struct ApplyUpdate
        {
            Store& store;
            ApplyUpdate(Store& store)
                : store(store)
            {}
            void operator()(StateUpdateCreateServer& update){store(update);}
            void operator()(StateUpdateCreateStream& update){store(update);}
            void operator()(StateUpdateRemove& update)      {store(update);}
            void operator()(StateUpdateRestoreRead& update) {store(update);}
            void operator()(StateUpdateRestoreWrite& update){store(update);}
        };
        void operator()(StateUpdateCreateServer& update);
        void operator()(StateUpdateCreateStream& update);
        void operator()(StateUpdateRemove& update);
        void operator()(StateUpdateRestoreRead& update);
        void operator()(StateUpdateRestoreWrite& update);
};

}

#endif

Store.cpp
#include "Store.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse;

/*
 * There is no default constructor for CoRoutine.
 * But a non-coroutine object is allowed to exist.
 * So we have a single invalid co-routine that can be used
 * to initialize non-coroutine objects until we are ready to initialize them.
 */
CoRoutine Store::invalid{[](Yield&){}};

StoreData& Store::getStoreData(int fd)
{
    auto find = data.find(fd);
    if (find == data.end())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid Request: Exit applications");
    }
    return find->second;
}

template<typename T>
void Store::requestChange(T&& update)
{
    std::unique_lock        lock(updateMutex);
    updates.emplace_back(std::move(update));
}

template void Store::requestChange<StateUpdateCreateServer>(StateUpdateCreateServer&& update);
template void Store::requestChange<StateUpdateCreateStream>(StateUpdateCreateStream&& update);
template void Store::requestChange<StateUpdateRemove>(StateUpdateRemove&& update);
template void Store::requestChange<StateUpdateRestoreRead>(StateUpdateRestoreRead&& update);
template void Store::requestChange<StateUpdateRestoreWrite>(StateUpdateRestoreWrite&& update);

void Store::processUpdateRequest()
{
    std::unique_lock        lock(updateMutex);
    ApplyUpdate             updater{*this};
    for (auto& update: updates)
    {
        std::visit(updater, update);
        /* This visit calls one of the operators below based on the type of the request */
    }
    updates.clear();
}

void Store::operator()(StateUpdateCreateServer& update)
{
    auto [iter, ok] = data.insert_or_assign(update.fd,
                                            ServerData{std::move(update.server),
                                                       std::move(invalid),
                                                       std::move(update.readEvent),
                                                       &update.pynt
                                                      });

    ServerData& data = std::get<ServerData>(iter->second);
    data.coRoutine = update.coRoutineCreator(data);
    data.readEvent.add();
};

void Store::operator()(StateUpdateCreateStream& update)
{
    auto [iter, ok] = data.insert_or_assign(update.fd,
                                            StreamData{std::move(update.stream),
                                                       std::move(invalid),
                                                       std::move(update.readEvent),
                                                       std::move(update.writeEvent),
                                                       &update.pynt
                                                      });

    StreamData& data = std::get<StreamData>(iter->second);
    data.coRoutine = update.coRoutineCreator(data);
    data.readEvent.add();
};

void Store::operator()(StateUpdateRemove& update)
{
    data.erase(update.fd);
}

void Store::operator()(StateUpdateRestoreRead& update)
{
    struct RestoreRead
    {
        void operator()(ServerData& update) {update.readEvent.add();}
        void operator()(StreamData& update) {update.readEvent.add();}
    };
    auto find = data.find(update.fd);
    if (find != data.end()) {
        std::visit(RestoreRead{}, find->second);
    }
}
void Store::operator()(StateUpdateRestoreWrite& update)
{
    struct RestoreRead
    {
        void operator()(ServerData& update) {}
        void operator()(StreamData& update) {update.writeEvent.add();}
    };
    auto find = data.find(update.fd);
    if (find != data.end()) {
        std::visit(RestoreRead{}, find->second);
    }
}

